# mouseReleaseEvent is not called

Tags: c++, qt, svg

I tried to implement a way for changing the background when an SVG button is pressed and reseting when it is released. My problem is that the mouseReleaseEvent is not called when I hide the QSvgWidget on which the mousePressEvent was called.

Here is my code:

*SvgButton.cpp*

```
#include "SvgButton.h"

SVGButton::SVGButton(QByteArray backgroundImage, QWidget *parent) :
    QPushButton(parent)
{
    this->init(backgroundImage);
}

SVGButton::SVGButton(QString backgroundImagePath, QWidget *parent) :  QPushButton(parent)
{
    SVGDom normalBackgroundImage(backgroundImagePath);
    this->init(normalBackgroundImage.byteArray());
}

void SVGButton::init(QByteArray backgroundImage)
{
    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
    _backgroundImageWidget = new QSvgWidget();
    _backgroundImageWidget->load(backgroundImage);
    setLayout(new QHBoxLayout(this));
    layout()->addWidget(_backgroundImageWidget);
    this->setFlat(true);
}

void SVGButton::select()
{
    this -> setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 10);");
}

void SVGButton::deselect()
{
    this -> setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
}

int SVGButton::tag()
{
    return _tag;
}

void SVGButton::setTag(int tag)
{
    _tag = tag;
}

void SVGButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
}

SVGButton::~SVGButton()
{
    delete _backgroundImageWidget;
}
```

and `BaseNavigationButton.cpp`

```
#include "BaseNavigationButton.h"

const int kButtonWidth = 140;
const int kButtonHeight = 70;

BaseNavigationButton::BaseNavigationButton(QString backgroundImagePath, QString pressedBackgroundImagePath, QWidget *parent)
    : SVGButton(backgroundImagePath, parent)
{
    this->setMinimumSize(kButtonWidth, kButtonHeight);
    if (!pressedBackgroundImagePath.isNull())
    {
         SVGDom pressedBackgroundImage(pressedBackgroundImagePath);
        _pressedBackgroundImageWidget = new QSvgWidget();
        _pressedBackgroundImageWidget->load(pressedBackgroundImage.byteArray());
        layout()->addWidget(_pressedBackgroundImageWidget);
       _pressedBackgroundImageWidget->hide();
    }
    else
    {
        _pressedBackgroundImageWidget = NULL;
    }
}

void BaseNavigationButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    qDebug() << "SVGButton::mouseReleaseEvent";
    if (_pressedBackgroundImageWidget) {
        _backgroundImageWidget->setVisible(false);
        _pressedBackgroundImageWidget->setVisible(true);
        //_backgroundImageWidget->show();
        //_pressedBackgroundImageWidget->hide();
    }
    QPushButton::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    //emit released();
}

void BaseNavigationButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "SVGButton::mousePressEvent";
    if(_pressedBackgroundImageWidget)
    {
        _backgroundImageWidget->setVisible(true);
        _pressedBackgroundImageWidget->setVisible(false);
    }
    QPushButton::mousePressEvent(event);
   // emit pressed();
}

BaseNavigationButton::~BaseNavigationButton()
{
    if (_pressedBackgroundImageWidget)
    {
        delete _pressedBackgroundImageWidget;
    }
}
```

The SVGDom basically just create a ByteArray from the SVG images. The code works, it is relatively correct, the only problem is that I described above.

Answer (score 1):

When you hide a `QWidget`, it lose the focus, and a Widget --or some child widget-- must have the focus in order to the events work on it.

Try this simple example:

1. Press the mouse button when the cursor is over a button.
2. Move the pointer out of the button without release the mouse button.
3. Release the mouse button.

As you will see, this not will trigger the button clicked --`clicked` is a `mousePressEvent` followed by a `mouseReleaseEvent`-- event.

Hence, you cannot receive mouse buttons events from hidden objects.

**What can I do to implement the "mouse pressed" style behaviour?**

If by *"mouse pressed style behaviour"* you mean: *"I want my widget style change when I press the mouse button"*.

Well, you can use the `setStyleSheet` function and applpy a CSS style to your widget. See [Qt Style Sheets Examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and your time(+1), I figured this out, just I thought that there are some workaround. What can I do to implement the "mouse pressed" style behaviour?

Comment: @flatronka I add some lines to my answer, check again.